# Deepface (FaceNet) python library in node.js

Tags: python, node.js, tensorflow

I want to use deepface a python lib based on [google FaceNet](https://github.com/davidsandberg/facenet) for face verification purpose in my app.

This library requires **TensorFlow**, so can I use this in the backend of my app that is written in **node.js** ?

Answer (score 1):

There is an [npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/facenet) for using FaceNet, although slightly outdated.

There is also an implementation [here](https://github.com/huan/node-facenet) that should be useful to you.